# Chain inner ovservable with outer observable

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code

```
  //#region GET ALL ORGANIZATIONS
  @Effect()
  getOrganization$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetOrganizationRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetOrganizationRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.dataService.getOrganization(action.payload.organizationId).pipe(
        concatMap(organization =>
          of(organization).pipe(
            map(organization => from(this.validateTokens(organization.access_token, organization.default_access_token)))
          )
        )
        ).pipe(
          switchMap(e => [])
        )
      )
    )
```

Basically what I am trying to do is

1. GET the data from => this.dataService.getOrganization
2. USE this data in => this.validateTokens(organization.access_token, organization.default_access_token) and return a value
3. USE both data of 1 and 2 inside the final `switchMap(e => [])`

The problem is I can't find a way to get the data from 1 inside 3.... I always only get the data of 2

Comment: What does `this.validateTokens` return?

Comment: just an object with some values